# Group by date (day of the month) in openerp-7 view

Tags: view, openerp-7

I want to set group by Date (DAY OF THE MONTH) in view, default openerp takes group by month, I don't want to do such code to add new char type field and then perform group by on that field.

Is there any pure solution for that ? Is there any feature in openerp that I missed.

Thanks in advance.